# shared QUndoStack among several QMainWindows?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, undo

Greetings all,

In my application,user can open several QWindows which share the same data.(save Data ,multiple Views)I needed to use one shared QUndoStack between the windows.

Undo/Redo works fine,but when any of a QWindow closed, Undo/Redo menu get disabled.I guess  its because the stack get cleared.

Any tips?
Thanks

Edit:
in every QMainWindow creation,I create the undo/redo QActions as follows:

```
   redoAction=undoStack->createRedoAction(getMainWindow() ,tr("&Redo"));
   undoAction=undoStack->createUndoAction(getMainWindow(), tr("&Undo"));
```

where undoStack is the shared QUndoStack instance.

Here is a snapshot of my application - http://oi53.tinypic.com/2rfbztg.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your reasons for sharing the undo stacks between the windows you may also consider using the QUndoGroup. Then you create separate stacks for each window, and group then with QUndoGroup. The undo/redo actions are created from the group, not from the stacks.

Answer (score 1):

create your `QUndoStack` instance without a parent and in `destructor` of `QWindow` check if it's the last 'QWindow' then delete `QUndoStack` instance.

Comment: hi,yes QUndoStack doesnt have a parent.And I never delete the QUndoStack instance until end of program execution.

Answer (score 0):

just pass the pointer of the current window to Qundostack & do as you want to do with help of redo & undo.